# Can't get eclipse to work with java

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-8, environment-variables

I am trying to install java and eclipse for the 2nd time on the same computer. I downloaded the java file from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
and eclipse from here:
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/lunasr1
When setting the environment variable something goes wrong. The system variable "path" is totally different from the one in the tutorial that I watched, and I don't know how to go from here. Also I couldn't find any similar problem on this forum...

File path looks like this:

`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk`

In eclipse when I try to compile my work, this pops up:

The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches.

So, what is it that i've done wrong, could it be some old files from the previous java installation causing all this trouble maybe? Or is it the environment variable?
(btw i use windows 8 on bootcamp)

Thanks in advance!

Valise

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches” when Eclipse for Android Project Dev](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240333/selection-cannot-be-launched-and-there-are-no-recent-launches-when-eclipse-for)

Comment: You might consider removing the first Java and Eclipse installs before attempting to install them again. There's no telling based on the information you've provided what your problem actually is. Showing us the contents of your PATH isn't sufficient on its own. You should verify that you have only one javac and java runtime. Then come back with letting us know where that tutorial you watched is located.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for pointing that out. I found that thread earlier today, but couldn't quite understand how to do it properly. I clicked on run -> run configurations and there my project name was written under "project:", but I had no idea as to what i was supposed to write under "Main class:"...So, the question remains, could it be my environment variable being incorrect, because i find it very strange that it is completely different from the 2 videos from other people on youtube.

Comment: @WineSoaked here are the links to the 2 tutorials i have watched: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CijsBUrIkw4 and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl-zzrqQoSE&list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28             and there is only one instance each of javac and runtime :).

Answer (score 0):

> In eclipse when I try to compile my work

Try to RUN, no?

Right click on your project -> Run As.. -> Java Application

Otherwise, Eclipse does not known what you when to do ;)

Comment: When clicking on "run as" there are no alternatives showing, it says "(none applicable)"

Comment: You must create a Java Project with a class containing main method.

    public class MainClass {
        public static void main(String[] args){}
    }

Comment: Thanks for replying! Now i get some errors instead: Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git                                                           Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git                                    I'll try to deal with this later this afternoon, but thanks for all the help this far!