# Need to add a "public static void main(String[] args)",

Tags: java, error-handling, jbutton

I'm trying to make a code in Eclipse that change the color and text on MyButton when clicked.

Edit: Got some help and the problem Error got solved. I now know that the code need "public static void main(String[] args)" where should that be put?

*After I try to run this code I get the Error "The selection can't be launched, and there are no recent launches".
However, I've googled it and saw that the error may be a common problem in eclipse. I am, although new to java and presume it would be more logical if there's wrong with my code rather than eclipse hate me.*

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

    public class Makke extends JFrame implements ActionListener{


        private JButton MyButton;

        public Makke(){
            setLayout(null);
            setSize(300, 250);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            MyButton = new JButton("Tryck För Blå!");
            MyButton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            MyButton.setBounds(100, 190, 60, 30);
            MyButton.addActionListener(this);
            add (MyButton);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == MyButton) {
                MyButton = new JButton("Tryck För Gul!");
                MyButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

            }

        }
        }
```

Translation:
There is some Swedish in the code "Tryck för blå" = "Click to get blue", "Tryck för gul" = "Click to get yellow" ^^

Comment: I didn't know people were still using Swing... If you have a choice, you should really check out JavaFX.

Comment: @Satya I get the error "The selection can't be launched, and there are no recent launches"

Comment: @Joffrey Ah, well there's a homework so I've got to use swing. But I'll keep that in mind in future coding :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240333/selection-cannot-be-launched-and-there-are-no-recent-launches-when-eclipse-for

Comment: @Satya Actually that helped me out thank you. Eclipse told me that I need  to insert "public static void main(String[] args)". Got any clue where this would be needed?

Comment: Your code is having many issues. @robbinmodigh

Comment: @robbinmodigh Then please tell your teacher to update his course ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You should set `setVisible( boolean b)` to `true`.

It Shows or hides this Window depending on the value of parameter `b`.

```
setVisible(true);
```

Add this line should be in the constructor of `Makke` class.

[Read setVisible(boolean) doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible(boolean))

---

2.Your `actionPerformed(.)` method

```
if (e.getSource() == MyButton) {
   //MyButton = new JButton("Tryck För Gul!"); remove this line
  //otherwise every time new button object will be created.
    MyButton.setText("Tryck För Gul!");//to change the button text
    MyButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
}
```

---

3.Need main method to run your app. Create a class contains main(-) to run your app, in that create object of `Makke` class.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String []args)throws Exception {

        new Makke();//now your window will be appeared.
}
}
```

[Read - Why main(-) method needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443459/why-main-method-is-needed-in-java-main-class)

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot! You're awesome :)

Comment: Yes! My bad, I'm new to this place

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new button everytime you click on it, but no clicklistener is added to that new object...
My recomendation is to do this  (or maybe better if you move to javaFX)

```
JButton myButton = new JButton("Text Button");
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
      myButton.setText("Tryck För Gul!");
      myButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, you're right. Did not think of that. Need to use Swing.* for my homework though but I will fix that :) Thanks