# How to fix The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches error

Tags: java, eclipse, github, eclipse-neon

I have imported a project from Github for a school project and whenever I try to run the program I get an error as shown.

[image: Error 1]

I have looked at several solutions for this error such as going into run configurations. The only problem with this is that when I go into run configurations and select Java Application, it does not let me select my project.

[image: Eclipse Neon Java Application]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What put inside `public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches” when Eclipse for Android Project Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240333/selection-cannot-be-launched-and-there-are-no-recent-launches-when-eclipse-for)